# From convergence in $L^2$ to convergence of the squares in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Given a function $f\in L^2(X,\mu)$ for some measure space $(X,\mu)$, we of course have that $|f|^2$ is a positive function in $L^1(X,\mu)$. I now came across the following. Suppose $\int_X |f_n(x)-g_n(x)|^2 d\mu(x)\rightarrow 0$ for sequences $f_n,g_n\in L^2$, then we also have $\int_X \big| \,|f_n(x)|^2-|g_n(x)|^2\big| d\mu(x)\rightarrow 0$. Can anybody give an idea on how to prove this?

Edit: We also assume the sequences are bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \left| |f_n|^2 - |g_n|^2 \right| = \int \left| |f_n| - |g_n| \right| \left| |f_n| + |g_n| \right| \le \int |f_n - g_n| (|f_n| + |g_n|) \le \sqrt{\int |f_n- g_n|^2} \sqrt{\int (|f_n| + |g_n|)^2} \le  \sqrt{\int |f_n- g_n|^2} \left(\sqrt{\int |f_n|^2} + \sqrt{\int |g_n|^2}\right)$$

Where I used Cauchy-Schwarz and Minkowski's inequalities.

Comment: I see this working only if the $L^{2}$ norms of $f_n$ and $g_n$ are uniformly bounded. Or is there an additional argument that you could provide to show that the last term goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @T.Eskin I think that the statement isn't even true. I think I came up with a counterexample. I'll post when I get done polishing it.

Comment: @T.Eskin if we take $f_n = (n+1) \chi_{(0,1/n)}$ and $g_n = n \chi_{(0,1/n)}$, then all the assumptions hold but $\int ||f_n|^2 - |g_n|^2| = 2 + 1/n \to 2$.

Comment: You're right. That counterexample seems to do the job. And your current answer proves the statement e.g. for uniformly bounded sequences in $L^{2}$.

Comment: True, it only works if the sequences are bounded. Sorry not to have mentioned that.